# Include and work with flowcharts and diagrams in posts

Tags: feature-request, images

I would really like to be able to include a wire frame in my posts.  I have a few questions that could really benefit from a flow chart, especially one that people could fill in as part of their answer.  Is there something out there like this (Mockingbird or Google docs plugin?)

If not, I think that Stack Exchange would really benefit from one. All that would be required is a site plugin that could read, render and edit XML code (for the diagram).  The diagram XML could exist in a special code section on any post or answer.  This code could then be copied, edited, quoted, etc. just like any other section on the posts.

Here is a great example of a diagramming system that saves and loads XML code:

https://www.draw.io/

Comment: What questions have you asked, or answers have you provided, that would benefit from a flow chart? I haven't yet seen a need, outside of people describing ux interactions, perhaps. As for wireframes, we have access to those already: just use an image.

Comment: I am curious about the workflow involving a Drupal module (Features).  Apparently, there are lots of incorrect ways to use Features which I would like to describe using a flow chart.